# I need a little suggetion in ov7670+arduino+ethernet shield

Tags: camera, arduino, ethernet

I am doing a project using Arduino Uno + Ethernet Shield + OV7670 camera(16 pins). I have solved the part with ethernet shield but I am quite confused about the camera part. How do I exactly connect the camera with the ethernet shield. I have the camera only. nothing with it. Can anyone help me to find a way out?

Answer (score 0):

You will need some duponts. (or cables)[DUPONTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U67D.jpg) and also breadboard [BREADBOARD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62lg2.jpg)

Comment: Thanks and sir you have a good sense of humor :) . But I think that much I have configured already.

Comment: Just find library fir camera just google ov0767 arduino. U didn't anything except serial port (as i know)